# Angular - Module not found (fs)

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-services

I am trying to use Node's fs module in my Angular app.

I assume that my problem lies in that Angular does not run in a node environment. Is it possible to run an Angular app in a node environment (or give it access to the file system in an other way) or should I create a separate Node server that can take care of this type of operations?

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import * as fs from "fs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class FileSystemService {
  constructor() {}

  schrijfNaarBestand(json: any) {
    const writeableStream = fs.createWriteStream(
      "../data/verrichte-metingen/test.json"
    );
    writeableStream.write(json, "UTF8");
    writeableStream.end();
  }
}
```

Comment: you should do this at the backend side

Comment: @tano I assume you mean I need to write a separate server to take care of it?

Comment: Yes, you can use the server you use to run production version as well. During development you can use proxy-config to use that server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confusion. Angular is a framework that works on the browser. Node works as a server. (On your local machine, or on a real server). So you can not use fs inside angular. If you are doing something on the server-side, you can use fs.

Comment: I am aware it runs in the browser and is there for considered a front-end application. I am not confused at all about that. My question is if I can break out of that context. You're repeating what I've said myself in my question.